# Do linux kernel dependencies imply the need for a system running a Linux OS?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I was told to use [this driver](https://github.com/DanielJeongADI/LKD/blob/master/MAX77958/drivers/mfd/max77958.c) to control some chip via I2C, which has a number of linux include statements. For example:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
```

Being a newbie to embedded programming can someone please clarify if this implies I can run this driver on:

1. a Linux OS machine (e.g. Ubuntu running on a PC) assuming I have some means of acting as an I2C master (e.g. FTDI USB-2-I2C chip or similar)?
2. an embedded Linux OS like that on a Raspberry Pi where I2C pins are readily available?
3. any ol' MCU (not running a linux OS) so long as the PC used to compile the
   firmware has the access to the required linux kernel libraries?

Are all/some/none of the above possible? Am I missing the mark entirely and the use case is totally different?

Comment: `not running a linux OS) so long as the PC used to compile the firmware has the access to the required linux kernel libraries?` I do not understand that part. How it can have access? It doesn't have a Linux OS, so there doesn't exist those headers.

Comment: I am trying to understand the difference between the requirements of the compiler platform (e.g. an ubuntu pc) and the requirements of the target system (e.g. an MCU like the one on an Arduino Uno). I'm a noob to C, but if I make a comparison to Java or Python imports (not sure if include statements are 1-to-1 there), but I can import all or some parts of a library, making use of only the parts I need. For example, I wondered if my firmware only needed the i2c functionality from linux, but not ethernet, can I compile code that uses the i2c functionality without ethernet and run it on an MCU?

Answer (score 1):

> Do linux kernal dependencies imply the need for a system running a linux OS?

Yes.

> a Linux OS machine (e.g. Ubuntu running on a PC)

Yes.

> an embedded Linux OS

Yes.

> any ol' MCU (not running a linux OS)

No.

> Are all/some/none of the above possible?

In my worldview, everything is possible. Theoretically, you or a vendor can provide a portability library to allow compilation of the kernel modules for non-linux devices. For example, they implement all the functions provided internally in linux kernel translating them to windows instructions, write all the used functions and headers. Because of instability of internal API in kernel and the size of the driver you mentioned, this is highly unprobable to happen.